# Write to a text file from Excel range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use Excel VBA to write a range to text file. I'm using the following script which I found:

```
Sub VBA_write_to_a_text_file_from_Excel_Range()
    Dim iCntr
    Dim strFile_Path As String
    strFile_Path = "C:\temp\test.txt"
    Open strFile_Path For Output As #1
    For iCntr = 1 To 10
        Print #1, Range("A" & iCntr)
    Next iCntr
    Close #1
End Sub
```

I would like to choose a path to save the file to. I found a code excerpt, but how can it be added to the code above for it to function properly?

```
fPath = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt", Title:="Save As")
If fPath = "" Then Exit Sub '//user cancelled
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code as shown below

```
fpath = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt", Title:="Save As")

If fpath <> "" Then

Dim iCntr

Dim strFile_Path As String

strFile_Path = fpath

Open strFile_Path For Output As #1

For iCntr = 1 To 10

    Print #1, Range("A" & iCntr)

Next iCntr

Close #1

End If
```

Comment: You don't need both strFile_Path  and fPath variables: just choose and use one of them only

Comment: Thanks June7 and Biju John. @user3598756 could you show your suggestion?

Comment: just substitute all `strFile_Path` occurrences with `fpath` (or the opposite, it's your choice) and remove `strFile_Path = fpath` statement

Answer (score 0):

How about doing it this way?

```
'Excel VBA Write to Text File:
Sub WriteToTextFile()

Dim FilePath As String
Dim CellData As String
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

LastCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

CellData = ""
FilePath = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\auth.csv"

Open FilePath For Output As #1

For i = 1 To LastRow
    For j = 1 To LastCol
    If j = LastCol Then
        CellData = CellData + Trim(ActiveCell(i, j).Value)
    Else
        CellData = CellData + Trim(ActiveCell(i, j).Value) + ","
        End If
    Next j

    Write #1, CellData

Next i

Close #1
MsgBox ("Done")

End Sub
```